# EF6 not saving changes

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

In the following code, I have wrapped a dbContextTransactions around multiple savechanges.  Everything from the ViewModel contains the correct data but for some reason, EF does not save the changes.  When I debug it, I'm not seeing any exception thrown as well.  Is there something special I need to do for a transaction that would prevent this from working?

I have validated that I am indeed targeting the correct database as I can query it through another page successfully.

```
    public static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    public static Guid AddPlanItem(PlanItemAddViewModel viewModel, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> images)
    {
        Guid planIdGUID = Guid.NewGuid();

        using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            using (var dbContextTransaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    PlanItem planItem = context.Plans.Create();

                    planItem.PlanId = planIdGUID;
                    planItem.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
                    planItem.PlanIdTitle = viewModel.PlanIdTitle;
                    planItem.PlanTitle = viewModel.PlanTitle;
                    planItem.SolutionTitle = viewModel.SolutionTitle;
                    planItem.ActivityCodeId = viewModel.ActivityCodeId;
                    planItem.RegionId = viewModel.RegionId;
                    planItem.OperatingCenterId = viewModel.OperatingCenterId;
                    planItem.DistrictId = viewModel.DistrictId;
                    planItem.ServiceCenterId = viewModel.ServiceCenterId;
                    planItem.PlannerRACFId = viewModel.PlannerRACFId;
                    planItem.SeverityId = viewModel.SeverityId;
                    planItem.Description = viewModel.Description;
                    planItem.PreviousPlan = viewModel.PreviousPlan;

                    context.Plans.Add(planItem);
                    context.SaveChanges();

                    foreach (HttpPostedFileBase image in images)
                    {
                        var imageSubmit = new PlanItemImage
                        {
                            PlanId = planIdGUID,
                            PlanImageId = Guid.NewGuid(),
                            Image = image.ConvertToByte(),
                            ImageTitle = image.FileName
                        };

                        context.Image.Add(imageSubmit);
                        context.SaveChanges();
                    }

                    dbContextTransaction.Commit();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    logger.Error("Error: " + ex.Message);
                    dbContextTransaction.Rollback();
                }
            }
        }

        return planIdGUID;
    }
```

Comment: You have an anti-pattern here that I call try/squelch. You catch an error and silently rollback. This is really awful. You need to handle the error, let the user know it happened and log something.

Comment: Remove try catch and see for yourself

Comment: If you try it without the try/catch, do you get any exceptions thrown?

Comment: I do not get an error without the try catch.  I just downloaded nlog and configured it.  No error in the log file nor exception in debug mode.

Comment: You can remove `context.SaveChanges()` from loop and you can write it above `dbContextTransaction.Commit();`

Comment: Have you stepped through the code?  Is `planIdGUID` correct or is it `Guid.Empty` ?

Comment: @AdemCatamak Not sure he can because he doesn't seem to have or set `PlanItemImage.PlanImage` therefore PlanImageId would be null without the intermediate `SaveChanges()`.

Comment: I stepped through and the entire object is in good condition.

Comment: @Neil, `PlanItemImage.PlanImage` (`PlanImageId`) not used after `SaveChanges`. Therefore, he can add multiple PlanItem and he can commit all changes one time. Actually, he does not need transaction. He does create own Id (Guid) and save it. He can add all item and at the end he can use `SaveChanges` one times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the code I see, I'm not quite sure what the issue could be (yet). Even so, we can take an approach to determine what the issue could be.

First let's simplify the simplify the code.

```
public static Guid AddPlanItem(PlanItemAddViewModel viewModel, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> images)
{
    Guid planIdGUID = Guid.NewGuid();

    using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        PlanItem planItem = context.Plans.Create();

        planItem.PlanId = planIdGUID;
        planItem.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
        planItem.PlanIdTitle = viewModel.PlanIdTitle;
        planItem.PlanTitle = viewModel.PlanTitle;
        planItem.SolutionTitle = viewModel.SolutionTitle;
        planItem.ActivityCodeId = viewModel.ActivityCodeId;
        planItem.RegionId = viewModel.RegionId;
        planItem.OperatingCenterId = viewModel.OperatingCenterId;
        planItem.DistrictId = viewModel.DistrictId;
        planItem.ServiceCenterId = viewModel.ServiceCenterId;
        planItem.PlannerRACFId = viewModel.PlannerRACFId;
        planItem.SeverityId = viewModel.SeverityId;
        planItem.Description = viewModel.Description;
        planItem.PreviousPlan = viewModel.PreviousPlan;

        context.Plans.Add(planItem);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    return planIdGUID;
}
```

This way we achieve two things:

1. By removing the try/catch we would be able to see any possible exceptions
2. By simplifying the save logic we can determine which where the issue is. If with this code everything works, we can then include the piece that saves the image and how it behaves.

Second, If everything works fine, we can add the next piece, the images but this time with the save changes outside the for bucle.

```
foreach (HttpPostedFileBase image in images)
{
    var imageSubmit = new PlanItemImage
    {
        PlanId = planIdGUID,
        PlanImageId = Guid.NewGuid(),
        Image = image.ConvertToByte(),
        ImageTitle = image.FileName
    };

    context.Image.Add(imageSubmit);    
}

context.SaveChanges();
```

**UPDATE**

The issue was caused due to the multiple SaveChanges() calls. Editing the code to a single one solve the issue.

Comment: Let me know if an exception is thrown or a new issue arrises after this testing this.

Comment: Code has been simplified to this version and still no transactions made it to the database.. Also no exception. https://ibb.co/cGXn5K

Comment: no exceptions ? not even from the output window ? They sometimes appear there even if the app keeps running.

Comment: Try getting rid of the `BeginTransaction` line too.

Comment: You are right, I must have missed this. I've updated the changes. Try testing again @GregN

Comment: Yeah I just noticed it as well.  It DID work after removing the transaction.

Comment: Great. Now we know this is not the issue. Now let's add the foreach inserting the images. This time, add a single outside the bucle instead of inside.

Comment: Just to clarify, you are asking to add one image in the same context?

Comment: Okay that's what I did.  I validated that the images AND the core item have been sent and saved to the database.  Now where the transaction comes in to play:  any part of these attaches fail I would want to rollback all savechanges.  So in this scenario, would one savechanges() roll back both the image and the plans transactions if it were to throw an error?

Comment: Yes, ideally that's what you would like to make most of the time, that way EF can perform a more optimize query when he knows all the information first hand.

Comment: Done and done.  Have updated the code to just one savechanges() at the very end.  I'm not sure where I was going with the DB Transaction but apparently not going very far.  That's for everyone's help.